# Rails 4: Create JSON object from specific Model data

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to implement a dynamic JSON object in a Highcharts function and I am wondering is there a clever ruby way to do this.

Basically I have Users in my rails app, each with a country of origin in the ISO-a2 format. I need to get the numbers of members for each country into this format....(value will be the dynamic variable)

```
var data = [{"code":"AF","value":"<%= ruby code %>"},
            {"code":"AX",.......and so on
```

I could start with

```
       country_array = Array.new
       User.all.map{|u| country_array << u.country}
```

But my attempts have resulted in horribly long messes. A suggestion if there is a smart way to do this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.all.group_by(&:country).map{|k,v| [k, v.count]}.to_h
```

This should give you a Hash with country codes as keys and the number of users having that country code as values.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this, using the database instead of Ruby to calculate the result:

```
counts = User.group_by(:country).count.map { |code, count| 
  { "code" => code, "value" => count }
}
```